# Is it possible to hide virtualization detection from software and drivers of guest Hyper-V machine?

Tags: virtualization, gpu, hyper-v

The goal is to perform GPU discrete device assignment in guest Hyper-V machine.
After setting up the Hyper-V, the real graphics card appeared in device manager of virtual machine but NVIDIA driver is not working on virtual machine (error code 43). So I need to "fool" the driver and make it think that it is running on a real PC.

AFAIK, there is a command for qemu which hides CPU signature. Can I do something simmilar in Hyper-V?

PS:

- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680
- Host: Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
- Guest: Windows 10 x64 Enterprise LTSB